# how to get a substring from right with T-sql

Tags: t-sql, sybase

Suppose I have a string like:
abc.efg.hijk.lmnop.leaf

I want the substring: abc.efg.hijk.lmnop. 
Means: Find out the first comma . from right, then get the substring from left to this comma

How to use t-sql string function return the substring with one expresssion?

Comment: find out solution: with reverse, charindex, I can do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First your'll need to reverse the string and find the character index of the first period, then subtract this number from the length of the entire string.  This value needs to be used at the length parameter of the sub-string function.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(55) = 'abc.efg.hijk.lmnop.leaf'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@S, 1, LEN(@S) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@S)))
```